# Custom Dimension with Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

In Universal Analytics

In case I need to set my custom dimension on page load with a single pageview, should I need to set it prior to send.

ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue); ga('send', 'pageview');

Let me know if this works.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would work.

There is also an alternative syntax where you can set the dimension with the page view call:

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'pageview',                
  'dimension1' : 'dimensionValue' 
});
```

The important thing is that there must be some kind of interaction event (pageview or event) to transmit the transaction value.

Comment: What's the `hitType` variable for?  I don't use that, and my dimensions seem to work...

Comment: That's because it defaults to pageview (but hits might also be events, transactions, user timings etc.)